# Chart axis values don’t correspond to data in column (dynamic range)

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, charts, scatter

I have a macro to create a scatter with no marks. It reads the x-axis values (in column X - TIME) that start always in zero. This column can have 20 values, or 25, or 60... but in a maximum of 100 values, it depends. This values have formulas (I don't know if that affects my problem). I have 2 series of values (y-values) both in columns Y and Z.

When I run the macro, it reads columns X, Y and Z, and creates the chart.

This is what I have:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim lastRow1 As Long
Dim lastRow2 As Long
Dim tempVal As String

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

Dim RowGraf As Long
Dim Invalue As Range
Dim Outvalue As Range

Dim ShName As String

With ActiveSheet
    RowGraf = .Range("x" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' the number or rows can vary, that's why this is here
    Set invalue = .Range("y4:y" & rowGraf)
    Set Outvalue = .Range("z4:z" & RowGraf)
    Set Time = .Range("x4:x" & RowGraf)
End With

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers).Select
With ActiveChart
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Time
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = Invalue
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = Time
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = Outvalue
    .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
    .HasTitle = False

    ' axis titles

    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Time"

    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "In/Out"

    ' add the legend
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""In"""
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""Out"""
    .SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)

    ' creates a new sheet for the chart

    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:="Chart"
End With

Sheets("Chart").Select
Sheets("Chart").Move After:=Sheets("Results")
End Sub
```

My problem is that no matter what values I have in column X, the chart that my macro creates have always x-axis values from 0 to 100, even if data ends in 8, for example. 
The series looks ok, the y-axis values are ok, but the x-axis values are completely different.

[image]

As you can see, for series Invalue, my max value of 107 occurs at X 2.17. In the chart, it occurs at approximately 18. There is a discrepancy between the data and the x-axis values.

If I try to "select data" clicking in the chart, the horizontal values are ok (they are the column values).
If I create this chart manually, the result is perfect. But when I run the macro, this problem happens.
I believe that this is related with this:

```
  RowGraf = .Range("x" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' the number or rows can vary, that's why this is here
Set invalue = .Range("y4:y" & rowGraf)
Set Outvalue = .Range("z4:z" & RowGraf)
Set Time = .Range("x4:x" & RowGraf)
```

Here I try to say that I want to select all the rows that have values, starting in row 4. My intent is to create a "dynamic range" for my chart - if I have 10 rows, it selects the 10 rows. If I have 20, it selects 20 rows, and so on.

In the following picture, I created the chart manually, and did not select the entire data - and it works ok:

[image]

**Another thing, and probably the most important:**
In column X, I have 100 rows with formulas. But if it’s *false*, they write “ “ – they don’t have a value (*a number*), but they have a formula inside.
When I try to select the data, it is probably reading all the 100 rows because all rows have formulas. I want it to select data if there is *a value.*

Comment: the x-values in your chart are the row numbers... (e.g. `MAX(Invalue) is at x = 14`). This should have something to do with the chart type (Linecharts instead of Scatterplots). Your code looks like it generates a scatterplot, which is fine, but the result kinda shows that there is still something off.

Comment: I believe that when I select the X-values, it selects the entire 100 rows, even if they are "blank" - i tried to creat a dynamic range, but i guess it selects the blank values also.

Comment: here -  RowGraf = .Range("x" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row i count the rows with data, right? but i just want to count the rows with VALUES.

Comment: Yes, you are finding the last non-blank row in column X,   so if any rows contain eg text, they will still be included. If you want to avoid this, re-organise your data: put all the unwanted stuff at the end of your ranges; determine how many rows of data you actually have for plotting in your chart; set your ranges for plotting in the chart accordingly.